# Block url specified folder or path using php

Tags: php, url, path

i have a Block specified Path.
for example `http://example.com/image` or `http://example.com/file.php` Some one going to this path it need showing `you dont have permission` or redirect another page.. How to do this for Php.. give me good examples..

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add index.php file in each and every directory that you want to prevent direct access. Inside index.php add

```
echo "<script>location.href='your_redirect_path';</script>"; or 

header("Location: your_redirect_path");
exit;
```